# How to change IP Address to other format?

Tags: sql, ssms

I need to include client's IP Address in signature code, by using this code to get client's IP Address:

```
SELECT  client_net_address as IPAdd
FROM    sys.dm_exec_connections
WHERE   session_id = @@SPID
```

I can now get the IP Address as:

> Ex: 192.168.1.24

How can i reformat it to something like this:

> 192168001024

I know we can do something like this in C# by using Split, PadLeft and Concat. But is it possible to do it in SQL Server too?

Thank You.

Comment: This is going to take a really ugly query in SQL Server, which has weak regex support.  I would recommend handling this in your presentation layer, rather than in the database.

Answer (score 1):

You have to write a function and can call from the query, there is no direct method to convert such notation transformation.